# Matrix Operations and Dependent Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonlinear-system, substitution, gaussian-elimination

Consider the following systems along with the corresponding substitutions:

---

\begin{align} \text{System 1} \\
2x^2 + 3y + 5z^z & = 7 \\
4x^2 + 9y + 10z^z & = 2 \\
x^2 + y = 2z^z & = 1
\end{align}
Suppose we let $u = x^2$ and $v = z^z$, yielding 3 equations with 3 outside variables.

---

\begin{align} \text{System 2} \\
4x - 3xy + 7y = 5 \\
8x + 11xy - 9y = 3
\end{align}
Suppose we let $u = xy$, yielding 2 equations with 3 outside variables.

---

\begin{align} \text{System 3} \\
-2\sin(x) + 6y = 1 \\
3x + 3y = 4 \\
\sin(x) + 2y = -12
\end{align}
Suppose we let $u = sin(x)$, yielding 3 equations with 3 outside variables.

---

The non-linearity in each system is masked by applying the substitution, so we could then convert each system into a matrix.  We can make similar substitutions prior to differentiating, in which case the chain rule is used to take account of the fact that $u$ is a dependent variable, dependent upon the variable of differentiation as defined by the substitution.  The chain rule ensures that the information in the outside expression and the information in the inside expression (the substitution definition) are both taken into account during differentiation.  Is there an analogous rule that can be used to perform elementary row operations on matrices with substituted/dependent variable coefficients?

Comment: Systems 2 and 3 are still non-linear after the substitution. For example, system 2 becomes a system with three equations, including the equation $u=xy$.  In system 3 you get a fourth non-linear equation $u=\sin x$ added to the system.

Comment: What makes System 1 different in this regard?  And why is it necessary to add the substitution equations to the system, rather than setting them to the side and considering them only when we need to manipulate one of the dependent variables in some way?

Comment: Correct, system 1 is not actually different. But no rules analogous to the chain rule in differentiation are needed when using substitution to linearize a system in this way.